# How yo insert data with image in AngularJs and PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have a CRUD table where I want to display users list with the profile pictures
I'm using AngularJs and Bootstrap
I have added upload file to the form and I'm able to insert to the DB but not able to save the uploaded file to my directory (/uploads)

My index form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>users</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables.bootstrap.css">
        
    </head>
    <body ng-app="crudApp" ng-controller="crudController">
        
        <div class="container" ng-init="fetchData()">
            <br />
                <h3 align="center">user's List</h3>
            <br />
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" ng-show="success" >
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                {{successMessage}}
            </div>
            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" name="add_button" ng-click="addData()" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x: unset;">
                <table datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr><!--data-visible="false"-->
                            <th width="10%">Image</th>
                            <th width="35%">First Name</th>
                            <th width="35%">Last Name</th>
                            <th width="10%">Edit</th>
                            <th width="10%">Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="name in namesData">
                            <td>
                                <img  id="{{name.id}}" ng-src="uploads/{{name.photo}}" class="thumbnail" height="50" width="50" >
                            </td>
                            <td>{{name.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{name.last_name}}</td>
                            <td><button type="button" ng-click="fetchSingleData(name.id)" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></td>
                            <td><button type="button" ng-click="deleteData(name.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="crudmodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" ng-submit="submitForm()">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" ng-show="error" >
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                        {{errorMessage}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="first_name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="last_name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="photo" ng-model="photo">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="photo">Choose file</label>
              </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="{{hidden_id}}" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="{{submit_button}}" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

var app = angular.module('crudApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('crudController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.success = false;

    $scope.error = false;

    $scope.fetchData = function(){
        $http.get('fetch_data.php').success(function(data){
            $scope.namesData = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.openModal = function(){
        var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodal');
        modal_popup.modal('show');
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function(){
        var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodal');
        modal_popup.modal('hide');
    };

    $scope.addData = function(){
        $scope.modalTitle = 'Add Data';
        $scope.submit_button = 'Insert';
        $scope.openModal();
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function(){
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:{'photo':$scope.photo, 'first_name':$scope.first_name, 'last_name':$scope.last_name, 'action':$scope.submit_button, 'id':$scope.hidden_id}
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data.error != '')
            {
                $scope.success = false;
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = data.error;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.error = false;
                $scope.successMessage = data.message;
                $scope.form_data = {};
                $scope.closeModal();
                $scope.fetchData();
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.fetchSingleData = function(id){
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:{'id':id, 'action':'fetch_single_data'}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.photo = data.photo;
            $scope.first_name = data.first_name;
            $scope.last_name = data.last_name;
            $scope.hidden_id = id;
            $scope.modalTitle = 'Edit Data';
            $scope.submit_button = 'Edit';
            $scope.openModal();
        });
    };

    $scope.deleteData = function(id){
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
        {
            $http({
                method:"POST",
                url:"insert.php",
                data:{'id':id, 'action':'Delete'}
            }).success(function(data){
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.error = false;
                $scope.successMessage = data.message;
                $scope.fetchData();
            }); 
        }
    };

});

</script>
```

Insert file which I'm unable to insert images

```
<?php

//insert.php

include('database_connection.php');

$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$error = '';
$message = '';
$validation_error = '';
$first_name = '';
$last_name = '';

if($form_data->action == 'fetch_single_data')
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample WHERE id='".$form_data->id."'";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $output['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    }
}
elseif($form_data->action == "Delete")
{
    $query = "
    DELETE FROM tbl_sample WHERE id='".$form_data->id."'
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
        $output['message'] = 'Data Deleted';
    }
}
else
{
    if(empty($form_data->first_name))
    {
        $error[] = 'First Name is Required';
    }
    else
    {
        $first_name = $form_data->first_name;
    }

    if(empty($form_data->last_name))
    {
        $error[] = 'Last Name is Required';
    }
    else
    {
        $last_name = $form_data->last_name;
    }

    if(empty($error))
    {
        if($form_data->action == 'Insert')
        {
            $data = array(
                ':first_name'       =>  $first_name,
                ':last_name'        =>  $last_name
            );
            $query = "
            INSERT INTO tbl_sample 
                (first_name, last_name) VALUES 
                (:first_name, :last_name)
            ";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            if($statement->execute($data))
            {
                $message = 'Data Inserted';
            }
        }
        if($form_data->action == 'Edit')
        {
            $data = array(
                ':first_name'   =>  $first_name,
                ':last_name'    =>  $last_name,
                ':id'           =>  $form_data->id
            );
            $query = "
            UPDATE tbl_sample 
            SET first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name 
            WHERE id = :id
            ";

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            if($statement->execute($data))
            {
                $message = 'Data Edited';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $validation_error = implode(", ", $error);
    }

    $output = array(
        'error'     =>  $validation_error,
        'message'   =>  $message
    );

}



echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Fetch table

```
<?php

//fetch_data.php

include('database_connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY id";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
if($statement->execute())
{
    while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

I'm using PDO connection
How I can add insert image among the above function

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the problem really related to [tag:twitter-bootstrap]?

Comment: The data table will be users  table and i need to add profile picture

Comment: Uploading images with angularjs is not a straightforward process. I suggest you google it a bit. There are many examples out there